# Django - redirecting a user to a specific view after GET to a separate view, changing language settings

Tags: python, django, cookies, translation

I have a site with that offers 2 language choices - English & Japanese.

To change between the languages, A user clicks a button taking them to a view which changes the setting. Previously, it had always redirected to the home page but now I want to take them to where they were before.

The current path is passed as a url param which is then saved to a response variable, which then has it's language cookie set before being returned.

For some reason, when I use the parameter in the `redirect` function, the language cookie doesn't set at all but using `reverse` (i.e. when it was hard coded to go back home) wass working fine.

How do I get the `redirect` function with the param to work like the one set with `reverse`?

Thanks in advance!

**Code:**

Template Links:

```
<a href="{% url 'language' 'en' %}?q={{ request.path }}" class="lang-choice btn btn-primary">English</a>
<a href="{% url 'language' 'ja' %}?q={{ request.path }}" class="lang-choice btn btn-info">日本語</a>
```

Urls:

`path('lang/<str:language>/', v.change_language, name='language')`

View:

```
def change_language(request, language): # language is 'en' or 'ja'
    redirect_page = request.GET.get('q') # e.g. '/about/'
    # note: redirect_page == reverse('about') is True

    # make sure language is available
    valid = False
    for l in settings.LANGUAGES:
        if l[0] == language:
            valid = True
    if not valid:
        raise Http404(_('選択した言語は利用できません'))

    # Make language the setting for the session
    translation.activate(language)
    response = redirect(redirect_page) # Changing this to use reverse works

    response.set_cookie(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME, language)
    return response
```

Comment: What is the behavior you are seeing now? Any error messages?

Comment: Please show the exact code that worked (using reverse).

Comment: Thanks to both - i found a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround to the above problem.
Fixed by adding the `{{ request.resolver_match.url_name }}` to the a tag's query param and then called `reverse` on that query param within the view:

Link:

`<a href="{% url 'language' 'en' %}?q={{ request.path }}" class="lang-choice btn btn-primary">English</a>`

to:

`<a href="{% url 'language' 'en' %}?q={{ request.resolver_match.url_name }}" class="lang-choice btn btn-primary">English</a>`

The view is then refactored:

`response = redirect(redirect_page)`

To:

`response = redirect(reverse(redirect_url_name))`