# How to redirect to previous page after language changing?

Tags: django

When I am trying to use `next` it doesn't work because in `next`-url there are old language code so language doesn't change.

my template:

```
<a href="{% url "set_language_from_url" user_language="en" %}?next={{request.path}}">en</a>
<a href="{% url "set_language_from_url" user_language="ru" %}?next={{request.path}}">ru</a>
```

my url:

```
path('language-change/<user_language>/', views.set_language_from_url, name="set_language_from_url"),
```

my view:

```
def set_language_from_url(request, user_language):
    translation.activate(user_language)
    request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = user_language
    redirect_to = request.POST.get('next', request.GET.get('next', '/'))
    return redirect(redirect_to)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use redirect_to = request. META.get('HTTP_REFERER','')

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django's built in [set_language_view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view).

This is a view that can be used to change the language of the user, and when passing redirect_to, it will automatically build the correct url for the next page to go to.

You can check out the example provided in the docs.

You can also simply change your code to not include the path of the request, but the name of the url to redirect to, like this (Assuming you have a url in you url_patterns with the name 'view_page':

```
<a href="{% url "set_language_from_url" user_language="en" %}?next={{'view_page'}}">en</a>
<a href="{% url "set_language_from_url" user_language="ru" %}?next={{'view_page'}}">ru</a>
```

Your view:

```
def set_language_from_url(request, user_language):
    translation.activate(user_language)
    request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = user_language
    redirect_to = request.POST.get('next', request.GET.get('next', '/'))
    return redirect(reverse(redirect_to))
```

Edit:

For returning to the current request instead of predefined request (**I have not tested this, so I don't know if it will work**):

You could try [resolving](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve) the path of the current request, and reversing it again, passing in the correct arguments. This should return the exact url as before, only with a different language prefix.

```
<a href="{% url "set_language_from_url" user_language="en" %}?next={{request.path}}">en</a>
<a href="{% url "set_language_from_url" user_language="ru" %}?next={{request.path}}">ru</a>



def set_language_from_url(request, user_language):
    translation.activate(user_language)
    request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = user_language
    redirect_to = request.POST.get('next', request.GET.get('next', '/'))
    resolved_url = resolve(redirect_to)
    if resolved_url.kwargs:
        return redirect(reverse(resolved_url.url_name, **resolved_url.kwargs))
    else:
        return redirect(reverse(resolved_url.redirect_to, *resolved_url.args))
```

Comment: Django's built in set_language_view uses a POST method so I need a custom view

Comment: The code I posted is an alternative to Django's default set_language view, and should work for a get request, simply pass the name of the url, instead of it's path, and perform a reverse for the url_name in you `set_language_from_url`

Comment: Your code is work but I need that this view redirect to the previous page but not to the page that given in the template manually

Comment: I edited it, with some code I think should work, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: I got error 'Unresolved reference kwargs and  args'

Comment: Updated my answer, let me know if it's working for you

Comment: I have already find another answer but thank you for your code!https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56739938/django-redirecting-a-user-to-a-specific-view-after-get-to-a-separate-view-cha?rq=1